# How do I center a dynamic div?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if this question has been answered (I think it probably has), but how do you center this dynamic div?

(I want `#two` to align itself to the middle position of `#one`.)

Right now my jsFiddle does this: http://jsfiddle.net/sE8Sc/4/

**HTML :**

```
<div id="one">
</div>
<div id="two">
        <a class="stuff">a</a>
        <a class="stuff">b</a>
        <a class="stuff">c</a>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#one { width:100%; height:200px; background-color:#222; float:left; }
#two { text-align:center; float:left; }
.stuff { width:20px; height:20px; background-color:#444; margin:0 5px; float:left; }
```

I've tried `margin:0 auto;`, `text-align:center;` but still no dice. I'm not looking at declaring a defined `margin` like `margin:0 41%;` because if I wanted to add another `<a class="stuff">` to the list it would get out of position...

Anyone? This is probably some simple positioning error that I can't figure out.

EDIT : I was looking around, and I saw this demo by Nivo Slider -- http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/ -- how is it defining itself with a 960px width?

[image: centered div]

Comment: Are you trying to center `<div id="two">` in the body?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/sE8Sc/17/ The automatic *centering* of the elements is prevented by the fact that you put a `float:left;` on it.

Comment: @JeffNoel yeh that's true, though he also needed to center relative to `#one` rather than the window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to wrap both `#one` and `#two` in a containing element. That should set the width. Then all you need to do is remove all the `float`s (on `#one`, `#two` and `#two`'s children). **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sE8Sc/19/)**

```
#wrapper { width:500px; }
#two { text-align:center;}
.stuff { width:20px; height:20px; background-color:#444; margin:0 5px; }
```

New markup.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two">
            <a class="stuff">a</a>
            <a class="stuff">b</a>
            <a class="stuff">c</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Without the wrapper two would just be aligned to the center of your `window` (or a parent with a width).

Comment: I added an edit to be clearer. Perhaps you could take a look again?

Comment: ooh, wait -- that works! could you explain why? I removed the `float` elements and they just snapped into place...

Comment: @RenoYeo It only works if your `#one` element is 100% of the window size, otherwise you'll need to wrap it in a DIV, as my amended answer says

Comment: Yup, the `#one` element is 100%. One additional question -- if I wanted to add a small margin (10px 0) to it, how do I do it? Because right now its taking the entire object and applying a margin to it... http://jsfiddle.net/sE8Sc/18/

Comment: If you wanted to apply a margin to what?

Comment: to `#two`, like to create a gap for it in between `#one` and `#two`.

Comment: Oh, that's because you still have a float one `#one` - remove that too and applying a `margin` to `#two` should work fine.

Comment: ahh, I see. thanks for your help! I'd still be stuck over this simple issue if it weren't for you guys :(

Comment: Updated, look now - anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

You center a dynamic div by cimply giving it a `display: table` value

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/sE8Sc/20/

```
#two {
    text-align:center;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```